# Display HTML5 controls in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: winforms, html, css, webbrowser-control

Simple question. I have a WinFomrs app (C#) and there's a WebBrowser control which displays html to the user. The thing is I need to start using some of the css3 capabilities like rounded border for buttons.
I have tried adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` node to the html code with no luck.
What should I do? Do I need to change the control? Does anybody know a good alternative?

Edit: The html code I try to show displays correctly in every browser (IE9, Chrome, Firefox)

Comment: yeap, definitely a duplicate :( please close.